# Catching SIGTSTP in IPython

Tags: python, signals, ipython

Registering a signal handler for SIGTSTP works in the plain Python interpreter.

```
(py3)$ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:07:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> def handler(x, frame):
...     print("CAUGHT", x)
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
0
```

Now I hit Ctrl+Z several times, and it works as expected.

```
>>> CAUGHT 18
CAUGHT 18
CAUGHT 18
```

But, in IPython, it does not work. The new handler is called but the original handler seems to be called as well, and IPython is stopped.

```
IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: def handler(x, frame):
    print("CAUGHT", x)
   ...:     

In [2]: import signal

In [3]: signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
Out[3]: 0
```

Now I hit Ctrl+Z:

```
In [4]: CAUGHT 18

[2]+  Stopped                 ipython
```

Incidentally, I do not see the problem with Ctrl+C:

```
In [5]: signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
Out[5]: <function signal.default_int_handler>

In [6]: CAUGHT 2
```

What is IPython doing with SIGTSTP? Mysteriously, I can't find any occurrence of the string 'SIGTSTP' in the IPython 3.2 codebase.

Comment: About the only thing that can be reliably said about `signal.signal()` is that its behavior is wildly system specific and it uses the old signal(2) mechanism which has been deprecated in favor of sigaction(2) because of its major deficiencies.  I suspect that IPython's multi-thread design has much to do with the apparent multiple receivers. Neither behavior strikes me as obviously incorrect. On my linux system, both ipython3 and python3 treat SIGTSTP as terminal errors using your code.

Comment: IPython doesn't make much use of threads (there's only one extra thread, used for writing to the history database). And the signal module should ensure that signals are [handled on the main thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads). I'm pretty sure we don't set up any special signal handlers (except some stuff with sigint when doing gui integration). Maybe it's something to do with our use of readline?